# I think I saw a satellite disappear?

Tags: space, natural-satellites, satellite, identify-this-object

I was gazing out of my balcony, and all of a sudden I saw this red light move across the sky. I thought was that it was a star at first, but it didn't blink, so I thought maybe it was a planet but it was moving too quickly. So I thought maybe an airplane, but airplane lights blink too. So I thought I was hallucinating a bit, that’s when I looked at it again and it started to decrease in size, turn dark red and then disappeared. All of  this happened in seconds. Are you able to help me out on what I just saw?

Comment: A point of light becoming redder and fading sounds **a bit** like a bright satellite or the ISS passing over to the night side. If you go to [the Heavens-Above website](http://heavens-above.com) and enter your location and the time & date this happened, it will show a list of bright satellite passes. (Just a suggestion, as it could be other things like a meteorite, etc.)

Comment: ISS passing over can be quite startling.

Answer (score 2):

If it was about an hour before you posted the question, somewhere near India, then yes it was the International Space Station.

http://iss.astroviewer.net/observation.php?lon=77.20902120000005&lat=28.6139391&name=New%20Delhi

Since that website rolls with time, here is the data cut/pasted from today:

```
Fri, Oct. 21, 2016 Begin Maximum End 
Time (IST): 6:42:54 PM 6:46:02 PM 6:49:09 PM 
Direction: NW SW SSE 
Altitude: 10° 49° 10° 
Brightness: -2.7 mag
```